# BeforeSuite method in testNg did not initialized values when integrated with cucumber

Tags: java, automated-tests, cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm

Please suggest if I am missing something in cucumber as I am new to Cucumber and TestNG. Thanks in advance!!

I am getting below exceptions while executing the code using cucumber framework (running as JUnit Test)-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Header value cannot be null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at restprograms.GrpUpdates.getGroup(GrpUpdates.java:165)
    at resources.StepDefCommon.ValidateGetGroup(StepDefCommon.java:20)
    at ✽.When User get group from webportal(src/resources/FCreateGroup.feature:6)

package resources;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import restprograms.GrpUpdates;
public class StepDefCommon extends GrpUpdates{

    @When("^User get group from webportal$")
    public void ValidateGetGroup() {
        System.out.println("INFO :: Fetched Group");

        System.out.println("Debuggggggg" + getGroup().asString());

    //  System.out.println(res.asString());

    }
}
```

This code works and performs the operation as expected when run as TestNG code

```
//  @When("^User get group from webportal$")
@Test
    public void ValidateGetGroup() {
        System.out.println("INFO :: Fetched Group");

        System.out.println("Debuggggggg" + getGroup().asString());

    //  System.out.println(res.asString());

    }
}
```

I am initializing all the values in "loadProperties" method as below

```
public class GrpUpdates {

static Properties prop = new Properties();

/****** Common Group properties *******/
public static String glmsUrl; 
public static String putRequest;
public static String updateRequest;
public static String clientId;
public static String memberFile;
public static String globalURI; 

/******* Group Attribute properties ********/

/*** Loading properties in property file and assigning property values ***/

@BeforeSuite
    public static void loadProperties() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream propertyfile = GrpUpdates.class.getResourceAsStream("env.properties");
        prop.load(propertyfile);

        glmsUrl = "http://" +prop.getProperty("xcapHost")+":"+prop.getProperty("xcaport");
        putRequest = glmsUrl + "/" + prop.getProperty("AUID") + "/" + prop.getProperty("CREATOR") + "/" + prop.getProperty("GROUPURI");
        clientId = prop.getProperty("CLIENTID");    
        memberFile = prop.getProperty("MEMBERS_FILE");
    }       
public Response getGroup()
{
    Response res = given().
                   header("ClientId", clientId).
                   config(RestAssured.config().xmlConfig(XmlConfig.xmlConfig().declareNamespace("test", putRequest))).
                   when().
                   get(putRequest);
//                     then().extract().response().asString();
        return res;
    }
}
```

Getting the ecxeption for all the variables used in "getGroup()"

Comment: What does your `env.properties` file look like ? Can you please add its contents as well ?

Comment: Hello Krishnan,

The I am reading the values to form URI and pass to headers from env.properties

It looks like -
xcapHost = localhost
xcaport = 9080
MEMBERS_FILE = C://JavaProgs//data//member.txt
AUID = groupcreation
CREATOR = admin
CLIENTID = admin123
GROUPURI = group1

This file is not concern as if I don't use cucumber in "ValidateGetGroup" class but testNG, I am able to execute it with same env values.

Comment: I don't think the file is being read. You are basically getting back a `null` value when you do `clientId = prop.getProperty("CLIENTID");`